# how can i add information to my databse in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

i was writing a program about movies and i needed to create a database. so i did it . and after running the app when i wanted to add a movie to my list nothing happend . here is my code :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rigister_series);
    setTitle("Register series");
    Button btnsubmit;
    final EditText moviename,movieyear,moviegenre,directername;
    TextView textViewcount;
    final database_manager db = new database_manager(this);
    int result=db.getmoviecount();
    moviename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.moviename);
    movieyear=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.movieyear);
    moviegenre=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.moviegenere);
    directername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.directername);
    textViewcount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewcount);
    textViewcount.setText(Integer.toString(result));
    btnsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
    btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String Name=moviename.getText().toString();
            String Genre=moviegenre.getText().toString();
            int Year = Integer.parseInt(movieyear.getText().toString());
            String Directername=directername.getText().toString();
            movies_item movieslist=new movies_item();
            movieslist.movie_name=Name;
            movieslist.movie_year=Year;
            movieslist.movie_genre=Genre;
            movieslist.directer_name=Directername;
            Boolean result= db.addmovie(movieslist);
            if(result){
                toastshow();
            }else


Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

 private void toastshow() {
    Context context= getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater layoutinfalter= getLayoutInflater();
    View view= layoutinfalter.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,null);
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setView(view);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0,0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

}
```

and also my database manager :

```
 public database_manager(Context context) {
    super(context,"mydb" , null,1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query= " CREATE TABLE tbl_movies (" +
    "  id     INT    PRIMARY   KEY     AUTOINCREMENT   " +
                      "    NOT    NULL    " +
                      "   UNIQUE  ,  " +

    "  name              VARCHAR   NOT   NULL   " +
                       "   UNIQUE  ,  " +
    "  year               NUMERIC   ,   " +
    "  genre              VARCHAR   ,  "  +
    "  directer   VARCHAR    " +
    "  );  ";

          db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_movies");
    onCreate(db);
}

public List<movies_item> getmoviesitem(){

    List<movies_item> List_movies=new ArrayList<movies_item>();
    String query="SELECT
 movie_id,movie_name,directer_name,movie_year,movie_genre FROM tbl_Hesab";  
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()==true){
        movies_item h= new movies_item();
        h.movie_id=cursor.getInt(0);
        h.movie_name=cursor.getString(1);
        h.movie_year=cursor.getInt(2);
        h.movie_genre=cursor.getString(3);
        h.directer_name=cursor.getString(4);

        List_movies.add(h);
    }
    return List_movies;
}


public boolean addmovie (String movie_name,int movie_year, String 
 movie_genre, String directer_name){
     boolean result;
    String query="INSERT INTO tbl_movies(name,year,genre,directer ) " +
            " VALUES   
 ('"+movie_name+"',"+movie_year+",'"+movie_genre+"','"+directer_name+"') ";
    try {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
        result=true;
    }
     catch (Exception ex){
         result=false;

     }
    return result;
}
public boolean updatemovie(movies_item moviesItem){
    boolean result;
    try {
        String query="UPDATE tbl_movies SET name='"+ movie_name+"',year="+  
 movie_year+",genre='"+ movie_genre+"',directer ='"+ directer_name+"'"+
                "where id="+ movie_id+"";
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
        result=true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        result=false;
    }
  return result;

}
public movies_item getmovie(int movie_id) {
movies_item movies_item= new movies_item();
    String query= "SELECT * FROM tbl_movies  WHERE id="+ movie_id;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()==true){
        movie_name=cursor.getString(1);
        movie_year=cursor.getInt(2);
        movie_genre=cursor.getString(3);
        directer_name=cursor.getString(4);
    }
    return  movies_item;

}
public int getmoviecount (){
    int result=0;
    String query ="SELECT * FROM tbl_movies ";
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    result=cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    return  result;
}

 public boolean deletemovie(){
 boolean result;
 try {
    String query= "DELETE FROM tbl_movies WHERE id="+movie_id;
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.close();
    result=true;
}
catch (Exception ex){
    result=false;
}
 return  result;
```

}

```
public Boolean addmovie(movies_item moviesItem) {
    boolean result;
    try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO tbl_movies(name,year,genre,directer ) " +
                " VALUES ('" + movies_item.movie_name + "',"   
 +movies_item.movie_year + ",'" + movies_item.movie_genre + "','" 
 +movies_item.directer_name + "') ";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
        result = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = false;

    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

i just keep receving the failed message which means nothing happens. 
can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: use active android or SugarORM from these library its easy to maintain local database in your android application , Queries are in these libraries are so simple and fast, Both ActiveAndroid and SugarORm are internally working on Sqlite, But in these library its easy to create tables and save data in it

Comment: Have you added the permissions in manifest? post your error .

Comment: what toast does it show in result?

Comment: the toast that it shows is "failed" as i made it in order to know wheather the data added to the database or not  which is not adding anything

Answer (score -1):

Your database needs to have `.db` on the end for example `mydb.db`

If your using SqliteOpenHelper, you can call.

`db.insert(String tableName, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)`

All you need to do is add each column name and value to a ContentValues object.